# prepend backslash to python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string stored in a variable like so

```
s = '(copy('
```

and I want my output to be like this

```
out = '\(copy\('
```

I have tried to do the following

```
s = '(copy('
r = '('

# Option 1
# out = s.replace(r, '\' + r, s.count(r))

# Option 2
out = s.replace(r, r'\' + r, s.count(r))
```

But both options are giving me `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`
 which is understandable because it is telling me that a string somewhere isn't closed or some part in the string isn't escaped.

But of course, if I escape the backlash with something like

```
s.replace(r, '\\' + r, s.count(r))
```

It will give me output like this `\\(copy\\(` yet what I want is `\(copy\(`.

Any idea on how I could go about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `s.replace(r, '\\' + r)` is correct.

Comment: `s = "(count("; r = "("; print(s.replace(r, "\\"+r, s.count(r)))` prints `\(count\(` on my machine. How are you getting your output? Note that doing `>>> s` in a REPL will not always give the same output as doing `>>> print(s)`. The former may render additional slashes, and this is by design.

Comment: @Kevin I understand now, it is because I was outputting directly in a REPL and not using print. Thank you